# Flyback converter input current

Tags: flyback, calculation

[image: Picture of the question]

I have solved A and B of this question but i have no idea how to solve C. any help would be apriciated

Comment: What have you tried so far? Any calculation or simulation?

Comment: You know the load, how many watts are used? Since efficiency is given as 100%, and the input voltage is given, how much current is needed to produce that many watts?

Comment: if lossless, use law of conservation of energy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *I have solved A and B of this question*

Did you get 0.38462 for the duty cycle? What did you get for the flyback voltage? I have an answer but I want to hear what you calculated.

> *I have no idea how to solve C*

Hint: if the output power is 30 watts, what is the input power?

If you know the input power and you know the input supply voltage, what is the average input current?

Comment: 0,38 for duty cycle and 77 V for switch voltage. i was thinking that it has something to do with P=UI but i got unsure :)

Comment: @Mbadly I get 78 volts for the flyback voltage (30 volts + 48 volts - think about it). The input power is 30 watts yes? The input voltage is 48 volts yes? What would be the current from a 48 volts supply that produces 30 watts in a resistor attached? You don't need to know the RMS current or anything like that because the supply is DC.

Comment: So it is as simple as P = U*I so 0,625?
Sometimes the solutions are just to simple so i get unsure

Comment: @Mbadly Yes that's it and, if you want to check the duty cycle and look at the waveforms, [visit my website](http://www.stades.co.uk/Flyback/flyback%20DCM2.html) and don't forget to mark my answer as accepted as per [this link](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) towards the end. Website calculator picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iepq8.png